# Using pan and utensils

Tags: kashrut-kosher, fish, eggs

Can a pan used for frying eggs, also be used to fry sardines? Does this meet kashrut kosher laws?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Since eggs are pareve its ok. Nothing has to be kashered. Also, since scaled fish with fins, as sardines are, are not meat, as long as the pan is never used for meat, its a pan once kashered could remain so.

Comment: Remember what it says on the site, "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi." To learn about kashruth, go to your local Orthodox Rabbi and see http://www.kashrut.com/ and the article on eggs - http://www.kashrut.com/articles/eggs/.

Comment: "since scaled fish with fins, as sardines are, are not meat" - fish without fins is also not meat ...

Comment: @mbloch yes, right, of coirse. I seem to remember that a fish without scales is not necessarily ok and fins usually mean there are scales so it is ok to eat.  I'll check that again to clarify that all fish dont have scales and sometimes could have a shell even though they look like scaly fish do.

Comment: It is the reverse, scales is enough to be kosher as it means there are also fins (it is a mishna in Nidda), see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/fins-and-scales) for instance